# Update dictionary when same keys is pair

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an array like :

```
[{'term': 'outraged', 'score': 0.964, 'AffectDimension': 'anger'}, {'term': 'brutality', 'score': 0.959, 'AffectDimension': 'anger'}, {'term': 'hatred', 'score': 0.953, 'AffectDimension': 'anger'} .. UP TO 5200
```

Some of my values has same keys like :

```
{'term': 'hateful', 'score': 0.982, 'AffectDimension': 'anger'},{'term': 'hateful', 'score': 0.600, 'AffectDimension': 'fear'},{'term': 'hateful', 'score': 0.575, 'AffectDimension': 'sadness'}
```

Now I want to update my key with the same key pair.

```
json_array = {}


for all in emotion_puan:
    json_array[all['term']] = {all['AffectDimension'] : all['score']}
```

I did try above code but as you know dict key's must be unique if the same key will pair it just update score and AffectDimension (According to last one.) . This return

```
.... ,'hateful': {'sadness': 0.575},.....
```

Now I want to update my keys if the same keys values pair.

Excepted Output :

```
 .... ,'hateful': {'sadness': 0.575 , 'anger' : 0.982 , 'fear' : 0.600},.....
```

I hope you understand my question cause my english is not good.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try out this code:

```
json_array = {}

for all in emotion_puan:
    # create a dictionary for term if not exists
    json_array.setdefault(all['term'], {})
    # assign score for related term 
    json_array[all['term']][all['AffectDimension']] = all['score']
```

PS: you can use `json_array = collections.defaultdict(dict)` to omit `setdefault` call

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

ds = [{'term': 'outraged', 'score': 0.964, 'AffectDimension': 'anger'}, 
      {'term': 'brutality', 'score': 0.959, 'AffectDimension': 'anger'}, 
      {'term': 'hatred', 'score': 0.953, 'AffectDimension': 'anger'},
      {'term': 'hateful', 'score': 0.982, 'AffectDimension': 'anger'},
      {'term': 'hateful', 'score': 0.600, 'AffectDimension': 'fear'},
      {'term': 'hateful', 'score': 0.575, 'AffectDimension': 'sadness'}]

res = {}
for k, g in itertools.groupby(ds, lambda x:x['term']):
    res[k] = {d['AffectDimension']: d['score'] for d in g}
res
#{'outraged': {'anger': 0.964},
# 'brutality': {'anger': 0.959},
# 'hatred': {'anger': 0.953},
# 'hateful': {'anger': 0.982, 'fear': 0.6, 'sadness': 0.575}}
```

Note: `itertools.groupby` assumes your `ds` are sorted with the key. If not, use `sorted` or `list.sort` first:

```
ds = sorted(ds, key= lambda x:x['term'])
```